# Preventing user from open start menu

Tags: c#

I have a program that should prevent the user from opening taskmanager and from openinig Start Menu. I have already added code to disable taskmanager and need now to prevent user from starting Start Menu by the windows key in the keyboard. Has anyone an idea, plz?

Comment: That sounds like a job for "group policy", not code...

Comment: Incredibly, this question was *just asked* by a different user. See here: [How can I disable the Start button (but not the Taskbar) on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940796/how-can-i-disable-the-start-button-but-not-the-taskbar-on-windows-7/4941069) Executive summary: not possible in C#, but the [Start Killer](http://www.tordex.com/startkiller/) application will do exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't want a code exactly. I want any idea to solve the problem.

Comment: @Cody - Ok so there is a way to do job, because there is one could make it ?!

Comment: @Mr.DDD: That didn't make any sense. If you're asking, "How can that application do it if there isn't any code for it", then the answer is I don't know how that application does it. I *assume* it's by dynamically modifying resources in "explorer.exe", but the author isn't sharing his source code. Suffice it to say that I spent a long time running at this problem from various different ways yesterday, and it doesn't work in Windows 7. If you're using an earlier version, it's certainly possible.

Comment: Use `gpedit.msc` to edit policies. There is a lot of settings for you to experiment with :-)

Comment: @Jaroslav: You cannot disable the Start menu with a Group Policy. There's no such policy, and this is not supported by the underlying operating system.

Comment: Anyway, what is your goal. Mr.DDD? Both start menu and Task Manager are related to closing/opening applications. Perhaps you are trying to disallow users to run some applications? You can specify allowed/disallowed applications using admin. templates.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you can reduce a users access rights so they have *almost* nothing on the start menu, except shutdown / logoff.

However for ethical reasons there is no built in way to disable the start menu.

Comment: D' Sorry, but that's configuration, and so isn't programming related, so doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Ask on Stack Overflows sister site, [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 4):

```
IntPtr trayHandle = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
IntPtr buttonHandle = FindWindowEx(trayHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", IntPtr.Zero);
bool result = EnableWindow(buttonHandle, false);
```

Those three functions are WinAPI:
[FindWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow), [FindWindowEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html) and [EnableWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enablewindow).

Comment: According to the article I link to in my answer, this might no longer work in Windows Vista (and presumably also Win7). Though I haven't tried it out.

Comment: It is pretty much the only way how to do it programatically - you would likely have to modify the code for other op. systems.
I would not do it myself, though :-P
Messing with users this way is nasty. Using `gpedit.msc` is the way to do that properly.

Comment: @Jaroslav: There is no Group Policy setting for hiding/disabling the Start menu.

Comment: @Cody - you said in the other article there are three methods when compined taskbar disabled entirely. Can you explain it please??

Comment: @Cody: Not exactly, no. There is a whole section devoted to Start Menu and Taskbar and you can turn off Start Menu items there, essentially making the Start Button useless.

Comment: @Jaroslav: How do you figure that makes the Start button "useless"? The question pretty specifically asks for a solution that prevents the user from opening the Start menu. Disabling certain aspects of its functionality doesn't seem like the same thing. @Mr.DDD: The "Start Killer" application will do what you're looking for. I linked to it in the comment to your question, but [here it is again](http://www.tordex.com/startkiller/).

Comment: @Cody: I agree, it is not the same thing. But you are not the OP, I am just giving the OP some alternatives - is that so bad?

Comment: @Jaroslav : the code you put doesn't disable start button actually ?

Comment: @Mr.DDD: Different OS have different taskbar implementations. This works on Windows XP. It might be different on W7 or Vista, for them, you would have to find another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with a policy but if you really need to do it programmatically you can try the following (not sure what versions of Windows this supports).

You'll have to search for the process that is the TaskBar, then you'll have to search through all it's threads to find the start button. This CodeProject article shows how to do it: [Hiding the Taskbar and Startmenu (start orb) in Windows Vista](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/hide_vista_start_orb.aspx)

You might also have to create some keyboard hooks to disable the user opening the start menu via some keyboard combo.

Comment: The solution proposed in that article won't work in Windows 7.

Comment: @cody: I'll take your word for it, don't have access to Win7 to try and it's a fairly horrible way of doing things anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I spent far too long trying it yesterday for the asker of a similar question. I agree that it's a very misguided attempt at security policy, and it's frustrating that people aren't more appreciative of your attempts to help them. Still a good answer, just a caveat worth noting.