# Preventing user from open start menu

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing user from open start menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954539/preventing-user-from-open-start-menu)

Hi all. I have an application for children computer use, it prevents the user from openining task manager or even openinig Start Menu. I have done with most of project, but I want to pervent the user from pressing windows key in the keyboard so that Start Menu appear.
I have just asked this question in other site of Stack Exchange, but still have no really answer. I have searched in the web also. I am working on Windows 7. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: This question really belongs on stack overflow, not here. However, take a gander at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320584 which may help.

Comment: @TZHX : thanks, the article is useful.

Comment: Best solution is probably to use a group policy to disable the features you want to block. If the computer doesn't belong to a domain you should still be able to edit the local policy. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292504 for more information.